# Wrong indexPath.row after reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to get the `indexPath.row` of a button clicked inside a tableView row.

When the user clicks this button I get the `index.row` corresponding to the button very well, but when I add more objects to the source array to create more cells by calling `reloadData`, the `rowButtonClicked` in each cell it's no longer giving me the correct `indexPath.row` in example I press the index 20 and now the printed `indexPath.row` is 9.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to add the event to the button:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  lBtnWithAction = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(liLight1Xcord + 23, 10, liLight1Width + 5, liLight1Height + 25)];
  lBtnWithAction.tag = ROW_BUTTON_ACTION;
  lBtnWithAction.titleLabel.font = luiFontCheckmark;
  lBtnWithAction.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  lBtnWithAction.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lBtnWithAction];
   }
 else 
     { 
       lBtnWithAction = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:ROW_BUTTON_ACTION];
     }

//Set the tag
lBtnWithAction.tag = indexPath.row;
//Add the click event to the button inside a row
[lBtnWithAction addTarget:self action:@selector(rowButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;
}
```

To do something with the clicked index:

```
-(void)rowButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    //Get the index of the clicked button
    NSLog(@"%li", (long)sender.tag);
    [self doSomething:(long)sender.tag];

}
```

Constants.h

```
#define ROW_BUTTON_ACTION 9
```

Why it is giving an incorrect index when I change the initial items of the tableView? Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Without your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation it's impossible to know if you're reusing cells or not. Assuming you are you have given no signs that you're removing those UIControl actions so reusing a cell will result in a button which triggers multiple actions in response to a single control event.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation

Comment: "but when I add more items to te tableView and call reloadData, rowButtonClicked it's no longer giving me the correct index" In what sense is it no longer giving the correct index? You have not shown any data to back that up. It is giving you the tag of the button that was clicked. Are you claiming that that this is _not_ the tag of the button that was clicked? How could that be? And you have not shown at all what you mean by "add more items" - that doesn't happen anywhere in the code you showed. Maybe you are doing _that_ wrong. But who knows - you didn't show it! If you want help, show code.

Comment: @CGR when you create `lBtnWithAction` button, you can set the `lBtnWithAction`'s owener to the cell, and in the `rowButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender` function , you can get the `sender.owener ` , through by `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_myTableView indexPathForCell:cell];` you can get the indexoath, then check

Comment: my suggestion will be subclassing the uitableviewcell and implement a delegate method that informs when a button is selected. in the delegate just add the cell as a return param so you can check the indexpath of the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're messing up button tags. Once you set the tag

```
lBtnWithAction.tag = indexPath.row;
```

you won't be able to get button correctly with

```
lBtnWithAction = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:ROW_BUTTON_ACTION];
```

(assuming `ROW_BUTTON_ACTION` is a constant). `lBtnWithAction` will be `nil` all the time except when `indexPath.row` is equal to `ROW_BUTTON_ACTION`.

I would propose to subclass `UITableViewCell`, add a button-property there and then just refer to it directly instead of searching by tag. In this case you'll be able to use tags for buttons freely :) –

```
@interface UIMyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong, nonnull) UIButton *lBtnWithAction;
@end
```

And then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    UIMyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UIMyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell.lBtnWithAction addTarget:self action:@selector(rowButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    cell.lBtnWithAction.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You have tiger eye! Great!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply update you line -

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

to

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on this will be subclassing the `UITableViewCell` and providing a delegate for it to respond.

code:

```
 //MyCoolTablewViewCell.h
 @protocol MyCoolProtocol<NSObject>
 -(void)youTouchedMyCoolCell:(MyCoolTableViewCell __nonnull *)myCoolCell;
 @end

 @interface MyCoolTableViewCell:UITableViewCell
 @property(nonatomic, weak,nullable) id<MyCoolProtocol>myCooldelegate; 
 @end

 //MyCoolTablewViewCell.m
 @interface MyCoolTableViewCell(){
    UIButton *mySuperCoolButton;
 }
 @end
 @implementation MyCoolTablewViewCell

 -(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{

  if(!(self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])){
    return nil;
 }

 // init your stuff here
 // init button
 mySuperCoolButton = [UIBUtton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
 [mySuperCoolButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedMyCoolButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 return self;
 }

- (void)tappedMyCoolButton:(id)sender{
  if([_myCoolDelegate respondToSelector:@selector(youTouchedMyCoolCell:)]){
     [_myCoolDelegate youTouchedMyCoolCell:self];
  }
 }
 @end
```

then in your controller

```
// whatEverController.m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // get the cell
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCoolIdentifier"forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.myCooldelegate = self;
}

-(void)youTouchedMyCoolCell:(MyCoolTableViewCell *)myCoolCell{
    NSIndexPath *myCoolIndexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:myCoolCell];
  // then do whatever you want with the index path
}
```